# $materialDialog fails to show when used with angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, material-design

I have a sample plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/t5SnGrVLApqQ4OxI4FYT?p=info)

I have a login page and on a successful login, the user is redirected to the actual home page, which is similar to:

```
$state.go('home');
```

Now, after logging in, I have a button to show some dialog. Clicking the button fails to load the dialog. If the user refreshes the home page (post login) and then clicks on the button, the dialog opens successfully. 
I am not able to understand why this happens. Could this be due to a bug in angular-ui-router? Or am I missing something?

Comment: downvoting because you only linked to your code, you didn't put it here. It's good to link to the complete example but you should include the most relevant bits here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you went about this wrong, when using ui router you should let it control your states. I'm not sure why your dialog fails to show, but I do notice you're using `ng-click` to open it. A better way would be to make a button with `ui-sref` which maps to a sub state.

```
<md-button ui-sref="characters.create" />
```

then in your state definition define an `onEnter` instead of a controller.

```
.state( 'characters.create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'character/create.html',
onEnter: function( $mdDialog, $log, $state ) {
            var ev = null; // this should be the $event
            $mdDialog.show(
                $mdDialog.alert()
                    .parent( angular.element( document.body ) )
                    .title( 'This is an alert title' )
                    .content( 'You can specify some description text in here.' )
                    .ariaLabel( 'Alert Dialog Demo' )
                    .ok( 'Got it!' )
                    .targetEvent( ev )
            ).then( function( answer ) {
                    $log.debug( 'answer', answer );
                    $state.go( 'characters' );
                }, function() {
                    $log.debug( 'cancelled dialog' );
                } )
        }
```